# Visual Studio 2012 Localhost Alongside Apache (XAMPP) Localhost?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xampp

As of yet I am using VB.NET Visual Studio 2012 and I am wondering if installing XAMPP alongside could cause issues with the localhost?

The OS is: Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the Visual Studio Web Server, then it usually picks a high-up port which is free, so you won't have any problems there.

However if you have IIS and XAMPP running alongside each other, there are going to be issues if you try to bind either server to the same port as the other one, even if you are using host headers (IIS) or virtual hosts (Apache).

To get around this, simply change the port number on either IIS or Apache to something else, for example run IIS on port 80 and Apache on port 8080.